# Unusual Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

I was trying to delete alternate nodes in a linklist. I observed a strange behaviour.

```
void delete_alternate_node_LinkedList(Node *head) {
    Node *prev = head;
    Node *curr = head->next;
    while (prev != NULL and curr != NULL) {
        prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        prev = prev->next;
        if (prev != NULL) {
            curr = prev->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine except the head being `nullptr` when I use `free` to delicate or intentionally keep a memory leak but if I change the line `free(curr)` with `delete curr`, I get a segmentation fault.

Can anyone explain me the reason?

Here are the boilerplate codes

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node * next;
    Node(int data){
        this -> data = data;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }

    ~Node() {
        if(next) {
            delete next;
        }
    }
};
Node* takeinput() {
    int data;
    cin >> data;
    Node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    while(data != -1){
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else{
            tail -> next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        cin >> data;
    }
    return head;
}

void print(Node *head) {
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp -> data << " ";
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `free` and `delete` are not interchangeable. You `free` what you `malloc` and `delete` what you `new`. Don't mix them.

Comment: `cout` and `delete` are C++ features that do not exist in C. The C tag is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: So basically just change `free(curr)` to `delete curr`.

Comment: on top of not being interchangable with `new` and `delete`, `malloc` does not create objects and `free` does not destruct them properly. Valid uses of those two are really rare in C++

Comment: Your `Node` class does not respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but it might be. Either way, it's definitely something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Even when I add delete, it gives me error

Comment: If `head` is a `nullptr`, then `Node *curr = head->next;` is a seg fault.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar Does `delete` cause the crash, or does it simply allow your code to reach a later, different error. If it causes the crash, look into the rule of 3/5/0 mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Delete works initially. But in later iterations it doesn't and causes exceptions

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah but the input is `1 2 3 4 5 6 -1` I know its an edge case I would handle later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your destructor has a problem
Let's assume 
`A->B->C->D->nullptr`
Now when you delete B it invokes destructor (if you use free it won't).
it will delete recursively C (which in turn delete D) and ..... till the end
so in next iteration you are holding on to a dangling pointer (C) and getting the segfault when you are trying to derefence it.

Comment: Okay. The boilerplate code was given by an Online judge and was read-only so I thought it was perfect. Now I see the problem. Thanks.

Comment: wc. you probably don't need to delete the next node. Instead use a function to delete entire list or used shared_ptr<> / unique_ptr<> (depending upon your usage).

Comment: The downside of `unique_ptr` in a linked list is the chain of destruction as the `unique_ptr`s clean up can overflow the stack if the list is long enough.